# Highcharts/highstock animate series when change the time period button

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple chart with rangeSelector and all buttons are working fine. Ideally, I would like to have a nice animation each time user hit the button and changes the time period. Currently it is not animating juts simply swaping the line.

How can I use animation when the button is clicked?

Here are the buttons with no animation:

```
rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
            selected: 2
        }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/allbuttonsenabled-true/)

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the setExtremes() function, you cannot use animation like the initial.